# MATLAB parse error in filename for wavread function

Tags: matlab

MATLAB claims a parse error(syntax error) at the \ before users in the filename extension. I can't understand why this occurs.

```
[x, fs] = wavread(C:\users\home\My Documents\MATLAB\o.wav);
sound(x, fs)
pause
xReverse = flipud(x);
sound(xReverse, fs)
```

Someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wavread` accepts a string argument to the path, so you have to call it like this:

```
[x, fs] = wavread('C:\\users\\home\\My Documents\\MATLAB\\o.wav');
```

In MATLAB, strings must be placed within single quotes and are effectively arrays of single characters. I believe it's also necessary to escape the backslash characters.